# How can I start with marionettejs yeoman boilerplate?

Tags: marionette, yeoman-generator

I have generate my first yeoman marionette application. 
I am having trouble get started though my question is 
how can I create a new itemView and displayed ?
Is there any example app using this boilerplate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the 3 Marionette Yeoman generatos. Choose whichever is convenient for you. Those are nicely documented so should be alright.

https://github.com/mrichard/generator-marionette

https://github.com/simonblee/generator-maryo

https://github.com/opus-online/generator-marionette-frontend

If you are looking for Marionette boilerplate, here it is.

https://github.com/BoilerplateMVC/Marionette-Require-Boilerplate

Hope that helps